# How can I stop Node from truncating my bash history?

Tags: node.js, bash, macos

I have been racking my brain as to why my bash history would be randomly truncated to 500 lines. Turns out every time I run a `node` command, it truncates my bash history file.

I have my bash profile set up such that it should never truncate:

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
shopt -s histappend
export HISTFILESIZE=
export HISTSIZE=
```

and this works, it's over 10,000 lines long (after having to repeatedly restore it from backups, no doubt losing commands along the way).

So, how can I stop node from doing this? I have node 20.10.0 installed via macports. Using `GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0)` on macOS.